# Differentiate between comma and comma space

Tags: php

I have a line coming from a CSV file like this:

"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5, Test 6"
Repeat for thousands of lines
There are no spaces between the items.

The comma between Item 5 and Test 6 is supposed to be there. I am trying to turn this line into an array.

```
$i=1;
$temp_array = array();
$number = COUNT($array);
while($i <= $number) {
    $temp_array[] = explode(",", $array[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

The array is currently outputting as this"

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Item 1"
            [1] => "Item 2"
            [2] => "Item 2"
            [3] => "Item 2"
            [4] => "Item 5
            [5] => Test 6"

        )
```

It should output as follows:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Item 1"
            [1] => "Item 2"
            [2] => "Item 2"
            [3] => "Item 2"
            [4] => "Item 5, Test 6"

        )
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `fgetcsv()`, which knows how to parse CSV files?

Comment: you can't parse the file using explode, use fgetcsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using PHP's function 'str_getcsv' -- might save you some trouble.

This function parses a CSV string into a PHP Array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Example:

```
$array = str_getcsv($csv_string, ",");
```

Comment: That worked perfectly by replacing the explode with str_getcsv. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Match the quotes literally.

```
$i=1;
$temp_array = array();
$number = COUNT($array);
while($i <= $number) {
    $temp_array[] = explode('","', $array[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

If you're using PHP 5 or greater, you can also do this:

```
$string = ''; //your string.
$delimeter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';

$newArray = str_getcsv($input,$delimiter,$enclosure);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Splitting strings with regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$temp_array = preg_split (",(?=[^ ])" , $array[$i]);
//                           ^ = "look ahead and make sure its not a space"
```

Tested in javascript